# How to write netCDF file with character entries in dimension variable using R

Tags: r, netcdf, dimension

I am not able to figure this out myself and thus was hoping for some ideas from your side.

I am trying to create a netCDF-4 file in R using the netcdf4 library. The nc-file should contain a variable, let's say temperature (ta), which has 4 dimensions: longitude, latitude, time, and pressure level.

Because of certain reasons I would like the last dimension "pressure level" to consist of character entries, like "upper level", "lower level".
Unfortunately, the function ncdim_def() only allows numerical values and not characters.

I have looked into many things including nco/cdo commands, but did not find a solution. Does anybody have an idea?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround for my question. So what you can do is:

- create an array with two lines; rbind("upper level", "lower level")
- create a dimension for the ncols (dim_p1) and one for the nrows (dim_p2) of the array. IMPORTANT: use ncdim_def(...,create_dimvar=FALSE)
- create a new variable with ncvar_def(...,dim=list(dim_p1,dim_p2), prec="char")
- use ncvar_put() to write the array into the variable

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of ncdim_def](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/ncdf4/html/ncdim_def.html) explicitly states that dimension variables need to be numerics or integers. Moreover, [this website](http://www.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/users/sean/Docs/netcdf/guide.txn_58.html) suggests that characters might generally not be supported for netCDFs, so this might be a more general limitation, not specific to the ncdf4 package.

So it seems not possible to use character-vectors as dimension variables, and you have to replace your character values by integer indices. Note that you can specify the meaning of each index as unit of the dimvar, for example like this:

```
    ncdf4::ncdim_def(name = "pressure level", units = "1 = low pressure, 2 = high pressure", vals = 1:2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can code upper and lower levels in numeric form ie. 1 for upper and 0 for lower levels of pressure.

This may require decoding back to string at a later stage.